Share data between parent page and its slots
I have the following folder structure:
app
  user
    [username]
      page.tsx // here I have a list of user's reviews
      layout.tsx // here I render {children} and {form} slots
      @form
        review
          [id]
            page.tsx // here I have a review edit form in a drawer

In the app/user/[username]/@form/review/[id]/page.tsx component I have to hit my DB again to get single review data although I already have it in review list in its parent app/user/[username]/page.tsx component.
I like the parallel routes idea, in my case it helps not to use query parameters to conditionally render different components which is always verbose and error-prone. Also with experimental: { typedRoutes: true } setting it is even easier, because all the routes are typed.
But it has a downside - additional DB calls.
Is there a way to avoid this?
